# How to Fix 404 Error After Fresh Magento 2 Installation

Tags: php, magento, installation, magento2

I'm trying to install Magento 2 to run on my local machine. I've followed the tutorial here: https://javapocalypse.medium.com/install-magento-2-4-on-windows-10-2021-a0c433e4ffc4, but when I go to localhost/magento I get a 404 error and am not sure how to fix it. I've tried replacing the .htaccess file in the root directory with the .htaccess file from /pub, and I've also tried moving index.php from /pub to the root directory, but have had no luck.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you not  to use this tutorial as many core file changes are suggested. You can use a Virtual Box setup and install Magento on Linux. It will give you faster load time and ability to run commands easily.

Comment: Okay! Do you perhaps have a link to a linux installation tutorial?

Comment: You may refer https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/build/development-environment/

Answer (score 0):

Check if you did below steps

1. Add entry in host files C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\vhosts.conf:
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub"
   ServerName  localhost/magento

   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
   ServerName localhost
2. Add entry in hosts file
   C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
   127.0.0.1  localhost/magento

I suggest you to use a different url like dev.magento.com instead of localhost/magento.